# Create jQuery Slider Range With One Handle Not Using Min/Max

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, uislider

Is there any possible way to create a slider that will create a range similar to what is done with one handle using min/max, only instead of min/max, starting the range from say 50 (on a scale from 1-100)? I realize this will most likely require modification of the slider or creating a plugin, just wondering if anyone has done this already or knows how to go about it.

I.e. something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/rangemin.html

Only, instead of the range going from the min, going off of where the handle is, and allowing the user to slide either left or right of that fixed starting point to create the range. Any help is appreciated, and I'd be glad to clarify what I need if that doesn't make sense! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question. You want something (what?) to be based on the initial position of the slider "thumb"???

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in having the range start on, for example, 50 (on a scale of 1-100) so that if I drag the handle to the right of 50, the range will be from 50 to wherever I drag it, and the same if I drag it to the left: a range from 50 to wherever I drag it to the left. Here's a mockup I created to illustrate my point: http://dev.foresightondemand.com/SLIDER/assets/images/slider_mockup.png Notice how the range doesn't start from the min or max, but from a fixed point in the center of the slider.